# What does LINQ use for sorting when OrderingByDescending with a DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ like this

```
.OrderByDescending(x=> x.LastWriteTime)
```

LastWriteTime is DateTime field

Does this sort all the way down to the second?

So if I have hh:mm:ss data will this be sorted to the second:

```
03/06/2021 12:39:03
03/06/2021 12:39:01
03/06/2021 12:38:50
03/06/2021 12:38:46
03/06/2021 12:38:42
03/06/2021 12:38:42
03/06/2021 12:38:37
03/06/2021 12:38:36
```

Comment: Yes. You can try it for yourself and see. In fact, it will even do it with more precision than just seconds.

Comment: You may want to lookup the `Ticks` property of a DateTime.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this sort all the way down to the second?

`DateTime` implements `IComparable<DateTime>`, and its [`Compare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare) method compares the `Tick` (0.1 ms) values, so it will sort at an even more precise level than milliseconds.